# Checkbox for disabling certain line(s) in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've tried to search this all around from the internet (or then I can't just describe my question right for the google). I am still such a noob in coding.

How I can make a checkbox to my website, which disables certain line(s) from the CSS file? I need this, because I want my website more mobile friendly to disable certain animations, which causes lag on mobile devices.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: why don't you just disable the unwanted css styles with media queries ?

Comment: Or just design it **mobile first** then ADD the animations with media queries for larger screens....it's the most logical option here.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot disable CSS styles from a CSS file. What you can do is overwrite those styles with additional CSS that is only applied on click of a button/checkbox.

That being said, making the user click a checkbox to change the site behavior is not a normal feature. I would recommend using CSS3 media queries to disable animations for all mobile users if you are concerned about mobile performance.

Answer (score 0):

simply put tag

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px), only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    }
```

and put the different CSS style depending on which devices you're using.

And look at this [website](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/) for further informations and examples.